# Should I prefer final static variable inside class or final variable inside a static method

Tags: java, static, final

Provided the final variable is used only inside one **static method**, should I declare it as final static member in class, or final variable in the static method.

If it is declared inside method, will it be initialized each time the function is called. (function is invoked a lot of times)

EDIT: The Variable is a `List` initialized using `Arrays.asList(...)` function

Comment: Yes. You should prefer the `final static` option.

Comment: it depends of want you want to do, final static could involve an issue in mutli-threading environment.

Comment: What does the variable *mean*? How is it initialized? Is it logically method-call-specific state, or type-wide state?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is a List of few constants, initialized using Arrays.asList(...)

Comment: If these are constants, I think you have answered your question. Constants should be `static final`. So should be this list. However, don't forget to make it immutable (`Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`).

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak my concern is, if it is a variable for a method, why should it be declared as class member. And if it is declared inside the method (static method) will it be initialized each time the function is invoked?

Comment: So you are generally suggesting that constants should be declared locally, unless they are used in more than one place? I think that it's another question which is primarily opinion-based. An argument could be that `static` constant is only one, while local variable will be once per call, but I doubt it will have impact on performance even in highly multithreaded application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is declared inside method, will it be initialized each time the function is called. (function is invoked a lot of times)

Yes. If you declare your variable inside the method, it will invoke `Arrays.asList(...)` each time the method is invoked.

If your variable has a costly initialization and/or the method is invoked a lot of times you should declare it as a `private static final` field.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want it to be a `static final` *in the method* itself. But Java does not support that. (C++ does by the way).

Unless the variable is a reference to an object that has startup overhead, I'd keep it as local as possible and write `final` in the method, rather than pollute the class namespace with a `final static` that's only used in one function. I'd trust the compiler to make any optimisations. Alternatively, create an inner class and declare it there.

Comment: If this requires work to initialize, you absolutely shouldn't "trust the compiler to make any optimizations". There could be side-effects involved, for example.

Comment: I think in that case I'd use an inner class.

Comment: Without knowing anything more than the scant information in the question, I'd prefer not to offer an opinion. There's a lot of context we don't know here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `final static` can be used. The element will initialize only once: at time of class loading. You can use this any number of times.

Comment: you should explain more, if you can use some examples, this can not be an answer!